# navigate back to same page on select-dropdown selection without clearing down controls?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-2, drop-down-menu

I have a text box and a drop-down selection on a page, plus a bunch of urls.

Clicking on the urls navigate back to the page with an updated url (for asp.net MVC2 functionality). This does not cause the texbox to clear down.

On my dropdown "onchanged" event I call `window.location = url;` (with url being the pages url with a sortOrder in the query string)... but this causes the pages text-box text to clear down.

Is there any way I can get the drop-down to postback to the page on selection changed and NOT clear down the text box?

Cheers,

James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with "clear down"? Does the dropdown lose it's selected item (e.g. gets reset to a default value)?

Comment: The text in the tex box is removed/cleared/reset. The drop down does not loose it's selected item because I render it using an MVC HTML helper to set its selected item, which is sourced from the query string. BUT when clicking the URL's on the page (that just link back to the same page, as mentioned) the text box text remains when the page is re-rendered. JD

Comment: Did you try including the textbox contents in the querystring?

Comment: @jdoig It would be great if you can share with us how you solved your problem.